# Order of appearance of a row within a pandas-groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe with the "index" or "order of appearance" of a row within a group.

For example, I have something like this

```
  col1  
0 John 
1 Lucy 
2 Jane 
3 Jane 
4 Jane 
5 Lucy
```

I want to `groupby('col1')` and get the order of appearance within each group.

And I am trying to get something like this

```
  col1  col2                
0 John 1
1 Lucy 1
2 Jane 1
3 Jane 2
4 Jane 3
5 Lucy 2
```

I hope I was clear. A priori it doesn't seem too tricky to me, but I just can't do it!

Thanks!

Comment: `groupby('col1').cumcount().add(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(by=['col1']).cumcount()+1
print(df)

    col1  count
0  John       1
1  Lucy       1
2  Jane       1
3  Jane       2
4  Jane       3
5  Lucy       2
```